# Running a Function via concatenation PYTHON

Tags: python, python-2.7

So what I'm trying to do is run a function using concatenation like this:

```
location = 1
"critter_" + location + "()"
```

and I was hoping that would run the function 'critter_1()' but apparently it doesn't work like that so I tried a couple of stuff since it gave me an error about str to int concatenation error. So what I tried was:

```
location = 1
"critter_" + int(location) + "()"
```

And it still didn't work so I came here to ask you guys if there is any way to actually do this.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There's almost certainly a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`globals()[function_name]`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) to get function object. Once you get the function object, call it like ordinary name.

```
func = globals()['critter_{}'.format(location)]
# OR  func = globals()['critter_' + str(location)]
func()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate problems:

1. You need to get the correct name for the function, so you need to convert your integer 1 to the string '1'. The easiest way is to just use `funcname = "critter_"+str(location)`, although you have more control over the way the conversion is done if you use the `format` method of the strings. (You've got the meaning of `int` almost exactly backwards -- it converts *to* an integer; `str` converts to a string!)
2. You need to call the function given by the string. For this, you can use a number of different methods. Simplest is probably just to call `eval(funcname+"()")`, although this isn't always safe. You can also use `funcname` to find the function in the dictionary which stores all globally defined function, `globals()[funcname]`.

Alternately, you could make your *own* list or dictionary of `critter_n` functions, and select from that:

```
critter_functions = {1: critter_1, 2: critter_2} #etc...
# ...

location = 1
critter_functions[location]()
```